# samsung galaxy a3: block all notifications except email and sms

Tags: sms, samsung, notifications

```
Device: Samsung Duos (SM_A300H) Android version 5.0.2
```

I want something very basic: that my samsung galaxy a3 works like a phone and makes sound only for call, sms and alarm. No more FB nor email nor whatever notifications.

I googled and found some [answers](http://galaxy-note-3.wonderhowto.com/forum/turn-all-notification-sounds-except-text-message-s-samsung-note-3-0156826/) that doesn't suit my device. They say: `Go to Settings -> Device -> Sound -> Default Notification Sound -> Silent. Next, set your text message sound to whatever you want.`

I have `Settings -> Sounds and Notifications`, and there I can silent notifications, but there is zero options for message.

Smartphones are so smart that they aren't phone anymore :(

---

This is what I see when I press sound button + options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For most phones with Android Lollipop: on any home screen (while music is off), press the phone's volume down button, then select **Priority**.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

**NOTE:** If you choose *None*, then you will not be notified of any call, message, reminder or even alarm.

If the volume button shortcut doesn't work, try going to *Settings → Sounds → Interruptions*. There will be an option to select *Allow only priority interruptions*. The [wording](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wording) may be slightly different though.

---

For some Samsung devices, [this FAQ](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/skp/faq/1074598)  will be helpful.

*See also:*

- [Android Lollipop has killed Silent Mode: here's how to use Priority Mode](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-activate-and-use-lollipop-priority-mode)
- [How to Set Up Android’s Priority Mode (and Get Back Silent Mode)](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-android-priority-mode-get-back-silent-mode/)
- [Set up 'Priority' mode on Android 5.0 Lollipop](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/setup-interruptions-android-lollipop-do-not-disturb/)

Comment: I wish it was simple but it is just not simple and that is the problem. When I press the phone's volume down button there is no priority, only the 4 regular choices (Ringtone, Media, Notifications, System)

Comment: Image uploaded. I don't have *Settings>Sounds>Interruptions*. I have *Settings > Sounds and Notifications*  But I have *Do not disturb* and set *Allow exceptions Alarms+Calls+Messages* really hope this will work coz so much energy lost on this!

Comment: Thanks very much, I have good hope [*Do not disturb* and set *Allow exceptions Alarms+Calls+Messages*] will make the trick

Answer (score 0):

There's a "blocking mode" in Samsung phones, in which you can select the apps you want to get notifications from. 
You can select the apps you want.

Comment: it just don't work, apps continue to ring, only the Do not disturb mode works so far